# How come two devices share the same major-minor device number?

Tags: linux, device-driver

I am reading "*Linux device drivers, 3rd edition*", and found something i can't understand.

in Chapter 3.2, the author said:

> Traditionally, the major number identifies the driver associated with the device.
>   The minor number is used by the kernel to determine exactly which device is being referred to.

Then I tried "ls -l /dev" to have a look, I found some thing unusual:

```
brw-rw----  1 root disk      1,   1 2011-08-23 23:52 ram1
brw-rw----  1 root disk      1,   2 2011-08-23 23:52 ram2
brw-rw----  1 root disk      1,   3 2011-08-23 23:52 ram3
brw-rw----  1 root disk      1,   4 2011-08-23 23:52 ram4
brw-rw----  1 root disk      1,   5 2011-08-23 23:52 ram5
...
crw-r-----  1 root kmem      1,   1 2011-08-23 23:52 mem
crw-r-----  1 root kmem      1,   4 2011-08-23 23:52 port
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root      1,   3 2011-08-23 23:52 null
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root      1,   5 2011-08-23 23:52 zero
```

These devices (ram1-ram5) all have a clone, with the same major-minor, but different name and type. I thought the author was saying "*major number means device class, and minor number means device index. So Major-Minor identifies a unique device.*"

Now I am confused. How come two devices could share the same major-minor?  What exactly the device numbers are?

Correct me if I was wrong.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

`mem`, `port`, `null`, and `zero` are character devices (as evidenced by the `c` the listing starts with). The `ramN` devices are block devices (hence the `b`). Major/minor numbers for block devices are independent from character devices, and vice versa.

Comment: so they are totally different files associating differnt devices? I also found this in LDD3, "**Modern Linux kernels allow multiple drivers to share major numbers, but most devices that you will see are still organized on the one-major-one-driver principle.**":, if so, how can the kernel choose the right driver for the device?

Comment: @Shello, first, this is out of date, dynamic assignment is much more common these days. Second, it's more accurate to say, one-major-and-type-pair-one-driver (ie, you can consider the type to be part of the major)